# Indexing columns crossing multiple tables

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have 2 tables, `headers` with 2 millions rows and `files` with 30 rows.

I have a query that supposes to get the total number of headers for each directory.

The SQL looks like below:

```
SELECT files.dir_id, COUNT(*) AS "TOTAL"
FROM headers
LEFT JOIN files ON headers.file_id = files.file_id
GROUP BY files.dir_id
```

Currently, executing the SQL above is taking 20sec. How can I index it to make it faster?

I have tried `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS HEADERS_FILE ON HEADERS(FILE_ID)`. This made `GROUP BY file_id` gets instant response (without left joining files table). However, it doesn't improve the performance for the original query above.

I'm thinking of something like `CREATE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON HEADERS, FILES(FILE_ID, DIR_ID)` should work. but I find no way in creating such index.

Appreciate for any help. Thanks!

Comment: Should this really be `headers LEFT JOIN files`, not `files LEFT JOIN headers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LEFT join prevents the database from using `files` as the outer table in the nested loop join.

Try using an inner join, and then adding the missing rows by hand; this might allow better optimization for the two subqueries:

```
SELECT files.dir_id, COUNT(*) AS "TOTAL"
FROM headers
-- LEFT JOIN expanded by hand for better optimization
INNER JOIN files ON headers.file_id = files.file_id
GROUP BY files.dir_id
UNION ALL
SELECT dir_id, 0
FROM files
WHERE file_id NOT IN (SELECT file_id
                      FROM headers)
```